# Shell script to add full read write and execute permissions to a directory and a file inside that directory

Tags: shell, chmod

I am very new to shell script but atleast I have tried somehthing but that does not work. I want to add read write and execute permissions to `httpdocs` folder of my website also `httpdocs/mysite` folder and a php file `httpdocs/mysite/_conn.php` for all users and groups.

I have the following in place but that does not work, `change-permission.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/date >> /tmp/event_handler.log 
chmod g=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs"
chmod o=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs"
chmod u=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs"
chmod g=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/mysite"
chmod o=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/mysite"
chmod u=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/mysite"
chmod g=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/mysite/_conn.php"
chmod o=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/mysite/_conn.php"
chmod u=drwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/mysite/_conn.php"
```

The above script does not work. What changes do I need to make in this `change-permission.sh` file ?

Answer (score 2):

`chmod o=drwx` doesn't work, you need to use `chmod o+rwx`.

**Full script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/date >> /tmp/event_handler.log 
chmod ugo+rwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs"
chmod ugo+rwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/mysite"
chmod ugo+rwx "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/mysite/_conn.php"
```

You can even combine 3 `chmod` commands into one as I showed above.

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know in a moment.

Comment: That did not work. May be some other scripts on the server is preventing to add the rwx permissions. Actually I am creating new website in Plesk through API and I have set a event handler which executes a `.sh` file whenever a new hosting is created. That `.sh` file has the above code which should apply the permissions. Unfortunately it does not apply. Any Idea ?

Comment: Create a new file using `touch foobar` on shell and then enter `chmod ugo+rwx foobar` to see if there is any error. Finally check permissions using `ls -l foobar` command.

Comment: As I said that I am new to `sh`. I have no idea how to do that. I mean I have no idea about `touch` and `ls -l` commands or hot execute them.

Comment: That's why I gave you full commands. You just have to enter those command on a terminal.

Comment: I am sure that you answer above is correct, but due to some other reasons that script is not working.

Comment: @Illusion if `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdoc` and such are owned by root you will need `sudo chmod`

Answer (score 0):

I've created a couple of functions to do the same idea, with varying levels of accessibility.

Each of them runs `find` and specifies file or dir (`-type` d or f), then sets the corresponding privs, thus including `x` for to make them readable.

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ chmod RWX ~~~~~~~
echo "Defining function 'chmod_group_rw' which requires single pathname passed"
function chmod_group_rw() {
  DEST=${1?'which path? (Can use *name* if all matches desired)'}
  find ${DEST} -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
  find ${DEST} -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
}
echo "Defining function 'chmod_all_rw' which requires single pathname passed"
function chmod_all_rw() {
  DEST=${1?'which path? (Can use *name* if all matches desired)'}
  find ${DEST} -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
  find ${DEST} -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
}
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ chmod RO ~~~~~~~
echo "Defining function 'chmod_archive_readonly' which requires single pathname passed"
function chmod_archive_readonly() {
  DEST=${1?'which path? (Can use *name* if all matches desired)'}
  find ${DEST} -type d -exec chmod 555 {} \;
  find ${DEST} -type f -exec chmod 444 {} \;
}
```

It helps not have to remember all the details, and can be used for any path you send it.

Any of these can be defined within a shell script and then called when needed, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/date >> /tmp/event_handler.log
function chmod_all_rw() {
  DEST=${1?'which path? (Can use *name* if all matches desired)'}
  find ${DEST} -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
  find ${DEST} -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
}
chmod_all_rw "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs"
```

Comment: As gleaned from the comments on @anubhava's answer, the ownership of the files you want to set the permissions for must be you, not root or any other user.